# using sessions in database operations

Tags: php, mysql

I have user sessions for the user to login. The problem is that anyone can open the server side links directly.

For example : http://mylink.com/foldername/json/json_example.php

If anyone browse the above link it opens directly.So I want to make secure to the database operations(some stores through JSON) and my server side PHP files by using sessions.I need to check user session before performing database operations and before opening of every page in server side.

The below code i used for User Sessions:

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();    
if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){
header('Location: home.php');}
?>
<html>
<head>
<body>
<section class="container">
    <div class="login">

      <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>">
        <p><input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" id="username"></p>
        <p><input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" id="password"></p>        
        <p class="submit"><input type="submit" name="login" value="Login"></p>

      </form>
    </div>
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['login'])) {
    require_once('db/connection.php');
    $username=$_POST['username'];
    $password=md5(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']));
    $query=mysql_query("select * from tablename where username='$username' and password='$password'");
    $row=mysql_num_rows($query);
    if ($row == 1){
        session_start();
        $a=mysql_fetch_array($query);       
        $_SESSION['user']=$a['username'];
        $_SESSION['pref']=$a['preference'];         
        header("location: home.php");               
        } else {
         echo "wrong username/password";
        }
    }
?> 

</section>
```

Please help in resolving the issue.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For blocking the access to the files that are included in others and should not be accessed directly: add this to the pages that are directly accessed, like index.php:

```
//This will prevent loading the included scripts as stand alone scritps.
define('SECURE', true);
```

and this to the scripts you don't want to be accessed by anyone directly

```
//Security check
!defined('SECURE') and exit("You should not be here.<br>Go back to the <a href='index.php'>home</a> page.");
```

For blocking access to any kind of file to the users that are not logged in, add this:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['user']))
    exit("You should not be here.<br>Go back to the <a href='index.php'>home</a> page.");
```

Comment: Happy to hear that. Could you please accept my answer if it answered your question? Thanks, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Is this something you are looking forward?

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['user'])){
header('Location: login.php');}
```

Note the `!` at the beginning of isset. This means that if the user variable is not set inside the session, it will redirect to `login.php`.